# How to allow group members to edit a page when said group members do not otherwise have edit access to site pages?

Tags: security, sharepoint-online

My SharePoint Online sub-site has three main security groups: MySiteOwners (3 people with with full control), MySiteMembers (20 people who can edit anything), and MySiteVisitors (hundreds who can read anything). But there is exactly one site page (named SpecialPage.aspx) that I want 50 people from MySiteVisitors to be able to Edit.

So I created a group on the sub-site called SpecialEditors, and the group name is visible at Gear > Site Information > View All Site Settings > People And Groups > SpecialEditors (but does not appear at Gear > Site Permissions > Advanced Permission Settings -- and I don't know why not). (I did not give any site-wide permissions to SpecialEditors because I intend to apply that group to a page only, and maybe that's where I went wrong.)

Then I went to Gear > Site Contents > Site Pages, and I found SpecialPage.aspx, and I clicked the three-dots > Manage Access, and I successfully added SpecialEditors with 'Can Edit' power, but that does NOT allow the people in SpecialEditors to edit the SpecialPage. So what did I do wrong? I'll be Grateful for your help!

Comment: What you describe should be sufficient to grant these 50 people access. Have you tried checking page permissions for an individual member?

Answer (score 0):

Here're steps to achieve your requirement:

1.Gear -> Site Permissions -> Advanced Permission Settings -> Create a groups including 50 people with edit permission.

2.Site Pages -> Select the page -> Manage access -> Advanced -> Stop Inheriting Permissions -> Grant Permission for the newly created group.
[image]

[image]

[image]